# How do I include quotes in the command inside the quotes of FOR /F

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, sed, cmd

This works fine.

```
 FOR /f "delims=" %%G in ('TagRead.exe %%L Genre') DO ( echo %GG )
```

But when I add a `sed` command to the ('...') it fails

```
 FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (
 'TagRead.exe %%L Genre ^| sed -E ''/Curtain^|Exit^|Spacer/^^!s~.*~Dance~'' '
 ) DO ( echo %%G)
```

output:

```
 sed: newline or end of file found in pattern
```

EDIT: Despite that this loopless command succeeds:

```
  TagRead.exe C:\temp\1.wma Genre | sed -E '/Curtain^|Exit^|Spacer/^!s~.*~Dance~'
```

How do I get the sed command and its quotes to be accepted in the (...) quotes?

EDIT: dbenham said: "the single quote never needs to be escaped when used with FOR /F. The outer most single quotes delimit the command string, and any inner single quotes work just fine."

Here's that solution:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (
'TagRead.exe %%L Genre ^| sed -E '/Curtain^|Exit^|Spacer/^^!s~.*~Dance~''
) DO ( echo %%G)
```

It fails:

```
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

EDIT: Here is a simplified and stand-alone version that is hopefully regarding the problem:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (
'echo xxx ^| sed -E '/yyy/^^!s~.*~zzz~''
) DO ( echo %%G)
```

succeeds:

```
zzz
```

This:

```
echo xxx | sed -E '/yyy^|uuu/^!s~.*~zzz~'
```

succeeds:

```
zzz
```

This:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (
'echo xxx ^| sed -E ''/yyy^|uuu/^^!s~.*~zzz~'''
) DO ( echo %%G)
```

fails:

```
'uuu' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

----------- THE SOLUTION -----------

The cause of failure wasn't the quotes. It was was some insufficiently escaped ^. From dbenham's 1), the minimum fix is:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (
'TagRead.exe %%L Genre ^| sed -E ''/Curtain^^^|Exit^^^|Spacer/^^!s~.*~Dance~'' '
) DO ( echo %%G)
```

and for the simplified version:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (
'echo xxx ^| sed -E ''/yyy^^^|uuu/^^!s~.*~zzz~'''
) DO ( echo %%G)
```

One may also remove some redundant ' :

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (
'TagRead.exe  %%L Genre ^| sed -E '/Curtain^^^|Exit^^^|Spacer/^^!s~.*~Dance~' '
) DO ( echo %%G)
```

and

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in (
'echo xxx ^| sed -E '/yyy^^^|uuu/^^!s~.*~zzz~''
) DO ( echo %%G)
```

EDIT: The solution in an instance that is simpler still:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%G in ('echo "xxx^^^|ppp" ^| find "x^^^|p"') DO ( echo %%G)
```

Comment: Please show the full command that works stand-alone (without the FOR /F), and then I can provide one or more options for including the command within FOR /F IN() clause.

Comment: @dbenham Thanks, I have done. Plus added a simplified example.

Comment: The posted loopless command cannot possibly work - you have mistakenly escaped the pipe. Please execute the command from a batch script without a loop, and when you have a working version, copy the command from the script and paste it into the edited question.

Comment: You're right. It was accepted, but did not succeed. I have corrected it. Thanks.

Comment: What supposed to show output with the command you show us? `for /f "delims=" %g in ('echo xxx ^| sed -E '/yyy^^^|uuu/^^!s~.*~zzz~'') do @( echo %g)`

Comment: @ChrisJJ Can you reproduce it with GNU sed? http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm

Comment: @Paul, I can reproduce it with no sed. See the 'simpler still' I have added at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FOR /F runs a command via a new cmd.exe process.

For example:

```
for /f %%A in ('echo hello') do echo %%A
```

FOR /F runs the command using:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c echo hello
```

At the time of this posting, the desired command has still not been properly posted in the question. Let us assume the correct operating command is the following (it makes no sense to me)

```
TagRead.exe C:\temp\1.wma Genre | sed -E '/Curtain^|Exit^|Spacer/^^!s~.*~Dance~'
```

You want to put the command in a FOR /F loop.

You have two options.

**1)** You can escape all the poison characters so that they pass through the cmd.exe command properly:

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('TagRead.exe C:\temp\1.wma Genre ^| sed -E '/Curtain^^^|Exit^^^|Spacer/^^!s~.*~Dance~'') do echo %%G
```

I am guessing that you originally had `!` escaped as `^^!` because you have delayed expansion enabled. The new cmd.exe process will have delayed expansion disabled, so you do not need additional escaping for this construct.

**2)** Or you can use the fact that CMD.EXE strips the outer most double quotes when the /C command is used. All you need to do is add double quotes :-)

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('"TagRead.exe C:\temp\1.wma Genre | sed -E '/Curtain^|Exit^|Spacer/^!s~.*~Dance~'"') do echo %%G
```

In this case, a `^` must be removed before the `!` because of how delayed expansion works: quoted escaped `!` = `"^!"`, and unquoted = `^^!`

Of course, all of the above is contingent on whether the original command (without the loop) is valid. It looks suspect to me. Regardless, the concepts above will work with most any working command put into a FOR /F loop.

Comment: EDIT - corrected escape sequence for quoted `!` when delayed expansion is enabled in option 2)

Answer (score 1):

try with `usebackq` http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%g in (
  `TagRead.exe %%L Genre ^
  ^| sed -E '/Curtain^|Exit^|Spacer/^^!s~.*~Dance~' `
  ) do ( echo %%g)
```

Edit: 
removed the doubles single quotes and keep just one.
But not sure how you can escape `|` inside `sed` command

Try to double quotes the `sed` pattern in this way without `usebackq`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%g in (
  'TagRead.exe %%L Genre ^
  ^| sed -E "/Curtain^|Exit^|Spacer/^^!s~.*~Dance~" '
  ) do ( echo %%g)
```

Edit:
Example with many quotes inside `()` and in command `sed` replacing the string `'d'a'y'` per `'n'i'g'h't'`

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %g in ( 
  `echo 'd'a'y'^| sed "s/'d'a'y'/'n'i'g'h't'/"`
  ) do @( echo %g)
```

Another switching `Winter\Summer` to `Summer\Winter`

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %g in ( 
  `echo Winter\Summer^| sed -r "s/(.*)\\(.*)/\2\\\1/"`
  ) do @( echo %g)
```

Comment: You probably need to double-quote it, i.e., `^^^|`

Comment: @HarryJohnston Seems with 7 ^ it work ``@for /f "usebackq delims=" %g in ( `echo yes^^^^^^^|no ^| findstr /c:"yes|no"` ) do ( @echo %g)``

Comment: Triple-quoted, right.  Well done!  In retrospect, I can see why that is necessary: the first pass processes the entire line, the second pass processes the command inside the backticks, and the third pass processes the command before the pipe, i.e., what by that point is `echo yes^|no`.

Comment: It work too in this way `@for /f "delims=" %g in ( 'echo yes^^^^^^^|no ^| sed "s/yes|no/no|yes/"' ) do ( @echo %g)`

Comment: USEBACKQ certainly doesn't hurt, but it doesn't help either.

Comment: The first fails thus: 'Spacer' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: @ChrisJJ Your question is: "how to include quotes in a loop" Something to which I have responded. Please ask a new question about your sed model which seems malformed. or try to explain what this line is supposed to do? `TagRead.exe %%L Genre ^| sed -E ''/Curtain^|Exit^|Spacer/^^!s~.*~Dance~'' `

Comment: @Paul "Your question is: "how to include quotes in a loop" " That's merely the title ;) My question is "How do I get the sed command and its quotes to be accepted in the (...) quotes?" and your answer (though appreciated) it does not solve that.

Comment: @ChrisJJ I already showed you how to:`for /f "delims=" %g in ( 'echo day ^| sed "s/day/night/"' ) do @( echo %g)` It's just that you do not want to understand.

Comment: Thanks, but your recodes of my example fail: http://i.imgur.com/ZmQKxbq.png and http://i.imgur.com/Wb1PH0v.png

Comment: @aschipfl - the single quote never needs to be escaped when used with FOR /F. The outer most single quotes delimit the command string, and any inner single quotes work just fine.

Comment: "I don't understand what's you are doing with sed" Fair enough. "Actually you are mixing macos SED switches (-E) with GNU SED on Windows" No. I'm using MKS sed.

Comment: @dbenham " The outer most single quotes delimit the command string, and any inner single quotes work just fine." I get the same fail. I have added that candidate solution to the question.

Comment: @dbenham "The outer most single quotes delimit the command string, and any inner single quotes work just fine." Verified - now that the ^ is fixed. So, I wonder what is ever the advantage of using backquotes as the delimiter.

Comment: @ChrisJJ - The huge benefit for USEBACKQ is to allow FOR /F to read a file where the name is enclosed within double quotes. That may be the only situation that requires USEBACKQ, but somewhere in the back of my mind is some other esoteric situation where it can be useful, but I am drawing a blank.

Comment: @dbenham Sorry to be unclear. I meant: I wonder what is ever the advantage of using backquotes as the delimiter _on the command string_.

Comment: @ChrisJJ - I understood what you meant. I see many people use USEBACKQ when executing a command with FOR /F, but I don't know of a single case where it is necessary or even useful. In all my experience, the same command could be executed perfectly well without it. If there is a useful case, then it is extremely esoteric. The only time I ever use USEBACKQ is when reading a file with FOR /F.

Comment: @ChrisJJ - The only other use I'm aware of is when you want to process a string literal, and you want the literal to include quotes, as well as some poison characters. `for /f %%S in (""^&"")` becomes `for /f "usebackq" %%S in ('"&"')`

Comment: @dbenham Thanks for the confirmation.